# How to refresh header view in UITableView DiffableDataSource

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource

I have table view and diffabledatasource with HeaderView that must contains collection view (simple FlowLayout). I need to update header but reloadData() doesn't work. How I can refresh correctly?

I tried to use reloadData()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.